# 'An error occurred' when saving a post on review queues

Tags: bug, status-declined, review-queues, first-questions, saves

I was reviewing in the First questions review queue. When I clicked on the save button, it successfully saves the post but gives an error `An unknown error occurred`.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Possible Meta dupe of this (MSE): ["An error occurred" when double-clicking on the new "Saves" icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382633/an-error-occurred-when-double-clicking-on-the-new-saves-icon)

Comment: Cannot repro with a single-click. Can repro by first saving, _then double-clicking to unsave_. Seems to be failing on the 2nd call to `/save?isUndo=true`. And it's not specific to the First Questions queue, can repro on any page.

Comment: The only consistent way to reproduce this I've found is: 1. Open the review. 2. Open the post *in a new tab* 3. Save the post from the new tab. 4. Go back to the review (refresh if you want. Doesn't affect it). 5. Try to Save. It always fails. Refreshing the review shows you an inactive save button, so pressing it will always try to save a second time. Note: you don't have to do the whole open in new tab and save - it's just to simulate the post already being saved when you see it in a review.

Comment: Wait, I just realised - I've apparently reproduced a different error. If you follow the steps from above, the button never gets active the like you see in the screenshot. It's always inactive but you get an error on the top after pressing it.

Comment: @GinoMempin I think you're right. I think it's a double-click. You don't even have to save first - if you click the Save button but the status of the post doesn't match what you're trying to change it to  (save/unsave) you get an error. So if you start from not saved then double click, it sends out two save requests and the second one fails. You then see exactly what the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97lK5.gif (note: I had to try double clicking a few times. It doesn't happen always. Maybe on a slightly slower connection there would be a higher repro rate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Saves icon has been removed from Review Queues. We discovered that this was inherited by Review Queues when we launched the feature. Previously, with bookmarks, it was intentionally hidden. Given that bookmarks were not enabled before in Review Queues, we have decided to remove the Saves icon. As such, I've updated the tag to status-declined.

For additional context, This was also reported in the [Saves Meta announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383185/1172320) as well.

Comment: Is [this other bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383530/the-saves-button-is-not-always-shown-active-when-it-should-be-which-leads-to-err) declined as well?